# React useState to JSON object type

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, use-state

I have a JSON data file that is imported with

```
import data from "../data.json";
```

It looks like this:

```
[
  {
    "name": "Emery",
  },
  {
    "name": "Astrid",
  },
  {
    "name": "Monto",
  }
]
```

A button click sets a state to the an item of the JSON array (e.g. Array item 2). My issue here is I don't know how to define the useState in a Typescript manner as I get the error that the name property does not exist. I know I could define a separate type definition file. Since Typescript is smart enough to know all imported JSON types and my state is part of that JSON, I was thinking that it must be possible without a definition file? Am I wrong here?

Comment: Have you tried defining a type `type MyObject = { name: string}` and then `useState<MyObject[]>` ? Your type can live in the same file as the one containing the component with the state.

Comment: Show us some of the code, where you do useState. What's the exact Typescript error? It should say what type Typescripts thinks a variable is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the real problem here is not with the JSON import since it shouldn't be a problem for TypeScript to tell that the objects in this `data` array, all have a `name` property.

Actually, it is necessary to set the type for your useState object. And this might be the reason you have that error. First, you have to define the type. For this object, it looks like the following should be suitable:

```
type MyType = { name: string }
```

Next, you have to add the type to `useState()`:

```
const [state, setState] = useState<MyType[]>(data);
```

Here `[]` means `state` is an array of objects of type `MyType`.

Comment: I was hoping it would work without setting the types on the useState explicitly but rather getting it from the JSON, but setting the types does work. Thanks a lot!!

Comment: Can you try `const [state, setState] = useState<typeof data>()`? I haven't ever done this but I am just curious if something like this would work.

Comment: Yes, this one I tried already, I was also hoping for it to work! Results in `property name does not exist on type {}` unfortunately.